# Return stream from http method

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my service, I have defined some method which will use `Http`.

For example:

```
getUsers(){
    this._http.get('someapi')
        .map(res=>res.json())
        .subscribe(success=>this.users = success; console.log(success))
}
```

What I am planing to do, is to set up this method so that it returns a promise, for example:

```
this.getUsers().subscribe(success=> DO SOMETHING);
```

or

```
this.getUsers().then(DO SOMETHING);
```

So far I got this:

```
getUsers(){
    var getUsersStream = this._http.get('someapi')
        .map(res=>res.json())
        .subscribe(success=>this.users = success ;console.log('DONE'))

return Observable.of(getUsersStream)
}
```

Which indeed allows me to do:

```
this.getUsers().subscribe(success=> console.log('after success'))
```

however, when I debug, I can see that console output is:

```
after success
DONE
```

Which doesnt really works like it supposed to. Where am I doing mistake?

**UPDATE**

Even though I the answer provided by Thierry works, I guess I will explain my question in bit more detail.

I have method `getUserById()` in my service, which does the following:

```
getUserById(someId){
    if(this.users.length){
        var i = _.findIndex(this.users, {"id":someId};
        return this.users[i]
} else {
        this.getUsers().then(find the user)//then should be invoked when users are there
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
getUsers(){
  return this._http.get('someapi')
    .map(res=>res.json())
    .do(success=>console.log('DONE'));
}
```

The problem is that `Observable.of` is faster than the HTTP request and you return the first subscription within `Observable.of`...

If you want an observable waits for a previous observable to execute it, you need to leverage the `flatMap` operator. Here is a sample:

```
getUsers(){
  return this._http.get('someapi')
    .map(res=>res.json())
    .do(success=>console.log('DONE'))
    .flatMap(success => {
      // return the new observable. For example a second request
      return this._http.get('someotherapi').map(res => res.json())
    });
}
```

**Edit**

Regarding your `getUserById` method of your service, I would try something like that:

```
getUserById(someId){
  if(this.users.length){
    var i = _.findIndex(this.users, {"id":someId};
    return Observable.of(this.users[i]);
  } else {
    return this.getUsers().do(users => {
      this.users = users;
    }).map(users => {
      var i = _.findIndex(users, {"id":someId};
      return users[i];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. So what is the difference between subscribe and do?

Comment: It allows to execute some processing without subscribing. See this doc: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md.

Comment: In your case, you don't really want to subscribe within the `getUsers` method. I guess that you only want at the end ;-)

Comment: I've updated my question to be more detailed what is missing - could you take a look. Nevertheless, I really like your answer, and it has helped me in other issue. Thank you!